# Get the size of big files in c++

Tags: c++, file, size

I have a big file about 4 GB and I want to get the correct size in bytes, I've tried `tellg();` but gives me incorrect result, I've tried a lot of functions but all of them fails, the idea is to have a function like:

```
    unsigned long long int GetFileSize(std::string path){
        //...code
    }
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size

Comment: Before C++17, solutions will be platform dependent (e.g different API between windows or unix).    What is your target platform?

Comment: You tried `tellg()` *how?*

Comment: `tellg` worked for me.  Maybe you've used it wrong?  Hard to say since you omitted the code with `//...code`.

Comment: @Eljay the data type that `tellg()` returns is implementation defined. It may be 32 bits or 64 bits. Sounds like it is 32 bits in jhon's case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121747/jack) in the comments, you can use the [std::filesystem::file_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size).

If C++17 is not an option, try this:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
unsigned long long GetFileSize(std::string path){
    struct stat64 file_info;
    if (stat64(path.c_str(), &file_info) == 0)
        return file_info.st_size;
    return 0;
}
```

Worked properly here with TDM-GCC 64 bit and a 8 GB file.